# LVM devices not showing in initrd but working on boot

Tags: centos, lvm, dd, initrd

I am currently working on a custom initrd based on the CentOS 6.7 (2.6) kernel with the [following modules](http://pastebin.com/EexGP2in) loaded.

The initrd is designed to backup files off a old RHEL system into memory, unmount the disk, wipe the disk and then finally `dd` a prebuilt CentOS system onto the disk.

The CentOS system was built on VMware then the vmdk was exported and converted into a raw format with `qemu-img`.

From testing the whole process works awesomely and once the `dd` is complete the system can be rebooted and start up fine.

The current blocker is that once the `dd` operation has completed, I can't mount the LVM disk to copy files back.

As you can see in the modules list the LVM drivers are there and are loaded, if I run a `fisk -l` it shows `sda1` as the boot partition (Non-LVM) and `sda2` as a LVM partition. When running `pvscan -vvv` it sees `/dev/sda2` but says `No label detected`.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are doing, and what LVM layout you are getting, all we can do is guess.

Comment: This was answered by @Anthon suggesting that the Kernel would not be aware of the new partition layout and that I needed to invoke a rescan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wipe the disk, the running kernel will not know about the partitions available.

You can run `partprobe` (as comes with the `parted` partitioning utility) to reload the correct partitioning info in your running kernel.

If you don't have `partprobe` (small discs not requiring `parted`?), you can use `hdparm -z /dev/yourdrive` as mentioned by [@ko-dos](https://serverfault.com/a/36039)

Comment: That work swimmingly! I tired looking for a way it could be done via invoking something in /proc so I wouldn't have to add more binaries but found that I already had `hdparm` which could do the same thing.

Source: http://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting

Comment: @LiamHaworth Glad this pointed to the right direction. Didn't know about `hdparm` being able to do this.